# Concurrent Singleton Class Python

Tags: python, multithreading, singleton

I'm trying to create a dictionary that is concurrently added to by different threads. To do this I created a singleton class which contains the dictionary instance. To access this dictionary I want a semaphore object (since the incoming key-value pairs are different for different threads) that allows multiple threads to add to the dictionary at once.

My attempt in python is below:

```
class recipeDict :

     initializationLock = threading.lock()
     semaphore = threading.Semaphore(10)
     dictInstance = None

     def _instance(cls):
         if not cls.dictInstance:
              with cls.initalizationLock:
                   if not cls.dictInstance:
                        dictInstance = dict()
         semaphore.acquire()
         try:
             return dictInstance
         finally:
             semaphore.release()
```

If my goal is to have each thread (25 threads) call recipeDict and access the dictionary contained inside for a bit (to add to it), and then release the semaphore, is this an appropriate implementation?

Comment: Why do you want to make it a singleton?  If this object is useful, why would you want to deny yourself the option of instantiating more than one per application?  There doesn't seem to be any reason for that.  And as Sraw points out in his answer, dictionary access is already threadsafe so in fact you don't have to do anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a metaclass for singleton purpose:

```
class Singleton(type):
    """
    An metaclass for singleton purpose. Every singleton class should inherit from this class by 'metaclass=Singleton'.
    """
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]
```

Second, create a class extended from dict and set metaclass to `Singleton`:

```
class RecipeDict(dict, metaclass=Singleton):
    semaphore = Semaphore()
```

Finally, implement your custom `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`:

```
class RecipeDict(dict, metaclass=Singleton):
    semaphore = Semaphore()

    def __getitem__(*args, **kwargs):
        with semaphore:
            super().__getitem__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(*args, **kwargs):
        with semaphore:
            super().__setitem__(*args, **kwargs)
```

But BTW, actually, getting and setting item from or to a `dict` **is** thread-safe in python.

ref: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm

Comment: Can you explain what a meta class is? Im just getting back into python after being in Java for a bit.

Comment: metaclass is the class of class. In short, class control how to create an instance, metaclass control how to create a class.